# How to return 404 when return type if MappingJacksonValue from @RestController

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have the following Spring @RestController method:

```java
public MappingJacksonValue getUserView(User viewer, Long vieweeid) {
    User viewee = getUser(vieweeid);
    if(viewee == null) throw new ResponseStatusException(
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "entity not found"
    );
    final MappingJacksonValue result = new MappingJacksonValue(viewee);
    Class view = Views.Minimal.class;
    if(viewer.getId().equals(viewee.getId())) {
        view = Views.Full.class;
    }
    ...some lines omitted...
    result.setSerializationView(view);
    return result;
}
```

Although this is working fine, I am not happy with throwing an exception to return a 404 if the entity requested is not found.

What is the best practice to handle this?

Comment: IMHO best practice is to throw an exception ;) What you could do is to create a custom `NotFoundException` so that you do not have to specify the `HttpStatus` every time.

Comment: Throwing an exception causes a stack trace / warning in the logs. Ugly. Also, using exceptions for control flow doesn't seem natural. 404 is not really an exception for a REST call.

Comment: On a default Spring Boot app the exception you are throwing does not cause a warning… but if you like you can also make your method return `ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>` and then return `ResponseEntity.notFound().build()` – see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like, you can make your method return `ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>` and then return `ResponseEntity.notFound().build()`:

```java
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> getUserView(User viewer, Long vieweeid) {
    User viewee = getUser(vieweeid);
    if(viewee == null) return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    final MappingJacksonValue result = new MappingJacksonValue(viewee);
    Class view = Views.Minimal.class;
    if(viewer.getId().equals(viewee.getId())) {
        view = Views.Full.class;
    }
    ...some lines omitted...
    result.setSerializationView(view);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```